# load data from mysql into sql business intelligence 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, datasource, business-intelligence

I use of business intelligence 2008 , I can connect to my mysql db without problem.
I want create Data source view. I can see all of my tables but when I include my tables ,it showa me this error:

> > ===================================
>
> ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.41]You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near '[].[adrankingoogle]'
>   at line 2 (myodbc5.dll)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle,
>   RetCode retcode)    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.get_FieldCount()    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.NewSchemaTable()    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetSchemaTable()    at
>   Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.DataSourceConnection.FillDataSet(DataSet
>   dataSet, String schemaName, String tableName, String tableType)    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.DSVUtilities.AddTableItemsInDataSet(DataSourceView
>   dsv, DataSourceConnection conn, ArrayList tableList, String tableType,
>   Hashtable usedFriendlyNames, ProgressBar progressBar, Int32
>   progressTotalCount, Int32& progressCounter)    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.DSVUtilities.ExportDataSet(DataSourceView
>   dsv, DataSourceConnection conn, ArrayList tableList, ArrayList
>   viewList, ArrayList sysTableList, ArrayList sysViewList,
>   IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ProgressBar progressBar)    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Wizards.DSVWizardForm.OnFinish(CancelEventArgs
>   e)

Answer (score 1):

Question has been asked before:

Get the MySQL ( 6.3.5 ) .net connector ( from MY SQL ) Edit the connection string ( in the designer paste in the connection string ) so that it has the new "SQL SERVER MODE=True" option.

Apparently it affects performance - but what can you do

My sample connection string...(passwords & userids omitted )

server=svr215;User Id=;password=;Persist Security Info=True;database=dw;sql server mode=true

[How do I use MySQL as data source in Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779976/using-mysql-as-data-source-in-microsoft-sql-server-analysis-services)

Comment: where I should set connection string?! I`ve set it in creating data source and it is like this: "Dsn=fard-pc/iranianMall32;uid=;sql server mode=true" but no thing has been changed!!